# How do I make sure that the updated state is returned before calling componentDidMount() in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm calling the this.props.fetchCustomers action creator in componentDidMount

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchCustomers(this.props.driverId);
    }
```

This is my mapStateToProps function

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        driverId: (state.auth === undefined) ? null : state.auth.googleId
    };
}
```

The problem is that `state.auth` is undefined at the time when `this.props.fetchCustomers` is called in `componentDidMount`. But later on it does get updated to `state.auth.googleId`. This I checked by putting `this.props.fetchCustomers` in `render()`. But the problem with putting this function in render is that it is called multiple times. I want to call `this.props.fetchCustomers` only once, but after `this.props.driverId` is set to state.auth.googleId.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `componentDidUpdate` function to achieve this whenever `driverId` changes.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.driverId !== this.props.driverId) {
    this.props.fetchCustomers(this.props.driverId);
  }
}
```

Comment: How does one save prevProps?

Comment: Why do you need to save them? That conditional statement just ensures that you only refetch the customers when the `driverId` prop changes. React will pass the `prevProps` to that function in your component after it has updated. Have you tried it?